# Why is axis =2 when calculating median of every cell in each matrix in a 3D numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, median

My task in python was to "Write a median_fits function which takes a list of FITS filenames, loads them into a NumPy array, and calculates the median image (where each pixel is the median of that pixel over every FITS file)."

I wrote the following (which was wrong):

```
import time, numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits

def median_fits(files):
  FITS_list = []
  for file in files:
    hdulist = fits.open(file)
    FITS_list.append(hdulist[0].data)
    hdulist.close()
  
  FITS_3D_arr = np.dstack(FITS_list) 
  median = np.median(FITS_3D_arr, axis=0)

  return median
```

And the correct solution was basically the same as mine except the median was calculated using:

```
median = np.median(FITS_3D_arr, axis=2)
```

And I don't understand why it's axis =2 instead of axis = 0 because aren't we calculating the median along the third dimension if we're finding the median of every cell in each matrix?

Comment: If each item in `hdulist` is an array of shape `(H, W)`, then `np.dstack` will concatenate them all along the third dimension to form a shape `(H, W, N)` array. `N` is the number of arrays in `hdulist` (or the `len` of). If you want the calculate the "median image", then I think your output should be shape `(H, W)`. In that sense it seems logical to me that `axis=2` to take the median across the `N` dimension so that it disappears.

Comment: If you used `np.array(FITS_list)` or `np.stack(FITS_list)`, the shape would be `(N,H,W)`.

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs I think what you said might be the reason? but I can't get my head around it, could you explain more? Because I thought axis =0 would find median of every data point across the 3rd dimension so median of every data point in amount of FITS files?

Comment: The axis you choose for `median` (or `max` or `sum`...) is the axis that is "reduced" or removed from the array. Since you want to reduce over the 3rd dimension (the one with length N), you should use `axis=2`. With `axis=0` you would reduce over the first dimension, which is the height of the images. That would leave you with a shape `(W, N)` array!

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs this explanation clarifies what you meant before, thank you